# regular expression pattern replacement *.xml

Tags: regex, sed

I am new to regular expression, and don't deal with it regularly so posting it as a question.

I want to replace

```
blah.xml                  
haha.xml
```

to

```
user/home/blah.xml           
user/home/haha.xml
```

I would prefer to do it with sed.

Cheers
SK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` as:

```
$ cat file
foo
blah.xml                  
haha.xml 
bar
$ sed -r 's#([^.]*\.xml)#user/home/\1#g' file
foo
user/home/blah.xml                  
user/home/haha.xml 
bar
```

To answer your question in the comments, try:

```
$ echo "file is blah.xml" | sed -r 's#(\w+\.xml)#user/home/\1#'
file is user/home/blah.xml
```

Comment: Thanks it works slight changes to my question.                            How can I change "file is blah.xml" to "file is /user/home/blah.xml"

Comment: I would broaden the match for the filename since there are many characters that might be in the name that aren't in the class '\w'.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's=\(.*\.xml\)=user/home/\1=g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's#^#user/home/#'
```

inserts user/home/ at the beginning of each line.